# My arguments are getting corrupted?

Tags: c++, corruption

Wow, I really have absolutely no idea what the heck is going on here. It's really boggling my mind. I have this method that I'm trying to get working (Stuff seems to randomly break without changes around here), I commented out parts so I can just get it to work at a bare minimum.

```
Font* ResourceLoader::getFont(const std::string &name, int size) {
size = size;
//for(std::list<std::string>::iterator itr = mPaths.begin(); itr != mPaths.end(); itr++) {
    //if(fileExists((*itr)+name)) {
        std::string filename(name);
        TTF_Font *font = TTF_OpenFont(filename.c_str(), size);
        TTF_SetFontHinting(font, TTF_HINTING_MONO);
        std::string err = std::string(TTF_GetError());

        Font* result = new Font(font);

        return result;
    //}
//}

return NULL;
}
```

My problem is the "size" argument is getting corrupted through the method. Here is what it looks like

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using [valgrind](http://valgrind.org) or other memory debugging tool? Chances are good that the problem is not in the code you have chosen to show us.

Comment: What's with `size=size` at the beginning of your method?

Comment: Assuming you're on Linux (by those screenshots), try using Valgrind, Electric Fence, dmalloc, etc. to help you find the code that is smashing your memory.

Comment: Do you have any evidence, *other than your debugger*, that the value of `size` is changing? Debuggers are notorious for displaying the incorrect value for a local after its last reference, especially if the code was compiled with optimization.

Comment: @Julio : Those screenshots look like Visual Studio to me.

Comment: I have not tried valgrind, I'll try that out. Changing the string signature didn't help out. I put size=size to try something, but I have removed it. I am using VS

Comment: Those screenshots are clearly from Visual Studio 2010. As such, Valgrind and so forth are probably not an option here.

Comment: @pmcs: Surely there is *some* equivalent tool for Windows. I recall using something called "Bounds Checker" ages ago. The state of the art has certainly kept up, hasn't it?

Comment: @GregHewgill I believe it's Purify. (no affiliation) http://www-01.ibm.com/software/awdtools/purify/win/

Comment: @GregHewgill: I have no idea if there's an open-source equivalent to Valgrind for Windows. The profiling and debugging tools with Visual Studio are really good alternatives though.

Answer (score 1):

Turn off compiler optimizations and see if this is still happening.

My guess is that the `size` parameter storage is optimized away by the compiler, since it's not being used in the function, and so the debugger shows you garbage data.

Something else you can try to see if that's what's happening is printing out the `size` parameter in the function after every line

```
std::cout << "size at line " << __LINE__ << ": " << size << std::endl;
```

I bet the value of `size` will stop changing.

PS. I just noticed you do use `size` in one of the function calls. Try printing out its value anyway. Also, why do you have the `size = size;` statement at the top of the function? What are you trying to accomplish with that?

PPS. To address your access violation -- make sure to check value of `font` before trying to use it downstream.

Comment: @ildjarn yes, I just noticed that -- see the edit. Still, it may be optimized out after the call.

Comment: I put size = size because VS wouldn't show me the value of size while the debugger was on the two lines I had commented out. I have since removed it. I put your code snippet in and the value stays the same before and after TTF_OpenFont. Problem is  that the font isn't being loaded. I really hate SDL_TTF, it's so picky about what font it can and can't load

Comment: OK, so it seems that your immediate problem (`size` value changing unpredictably) is solved, right?

Comment: @George : The access violation still hints at memory corruption. :-]

Comment: @ildjarn yeah, he should also check that `font` is not NULL.